# several instantiation of a class depending of user input

Tags: c#

I'm creating a bingo game where i have "Player" class with different variables in it. I want to ask the user how many players does he/she wants and depending of the input create as many instantiations as desired but i don't know how to do it. Here is my code:

```
int players = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for(int i = 0; i <= players; i++)
    {
        Player player +1  = new Player((int[5, 3]), "Player " + i);
    }
```

The expected result is to be able to instantiate a class as many times as a variable says.

Edit: This is the Player class:

```
public class Player
    {
        private int[,] playerTicket;
        private int ticketId;
        private string name;

        public int[,] PlayerTicket
        {
            get { return playerTicket; }
            set { playerTicket = value; }
        }
        public int TicketId
        {
            get { return ticketId; }
            set { ticketId = value; }
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return Name; }
            set { Name = value; }
        }

        public Player(int[,] playerTicket, int ticketId, string name)
        {
            this.playerTicket = PlayerTicket;
            this.ticketId = TicketId;
            this.name = Name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use a `List<T>` and just add a new instantiation to it on each iteration of your loop

Comment: Beg your pardon, but what does array (`int[,] playerTicket`) mean in Player's constructor? I mean - where do you use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int numberOfPlayers = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
//List which will contain each Player object
//Why use a list? A List is container which holds a reference to each
//Player object which is created in the loop,
//Reference to the List object
//https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

List<Player> players = new List<Player>();

for(int i = 0; i <= numberOfPlayers; i++)
{
    //Just instantiate a new Player object, make sure to pass in an integer for the second parameter of your constructor
    Player player = new Player(new int[5, 3], i, "Player " + i);
    //Add the Player to the List
    players.Add(player);
}
```

Edit your Player class:

Either add a constructor which accepts the two parameters or make sure to pass in an integer for the second parameter of your constructor:

```
//You should be setting your class fields to the ones passed into the constructor
public Player(int[,] playerTicket, int ticketId, string name)
{
            this.playerTicket = playerTicket;
            this.ticketId = ticketId;
            this.name = name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use List and .Add(T) method. e.g.:

```
int players = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
List<Player> activePlayers = new List<Player>();
for(int i = 0; i <= players; i++)
{
    activePlayers.Add(new Player((int[5, 3]), "Player " + i));
}
```

Comment: When you post an answer, your code will be seen by new programmers. It's important to follow the correct conventions of the language in order to not start people off on the wrong foot. So local variables should be `camelCased`. `ActivePlayers` would thus become `activePlayers`.

Comment: You can edit your answer to follow the proper C# conventions.